# iOS GHUnit and Core Data

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data, gh-unit

ers,

I recently integrated CoreData into my existing iOS application.  I have previously existing tests written around some domain and network functionality; that now needs to be retrofitted to use CoreData (instead of storing in userDefaults).

I have `GHUnitIOS.framework` included in my project.  However, all my tests are failing because the TestAppDelegate knows nothing about CoreData's `managedObjectContext`.  For reference as to what I'm seeing:

`[GHUnitIOSAppDelegate managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

This makes sense - the test app delegate doesn't have managedObjectContext as a property.  I'd love to add it, but since I only have access to the header files when using the framework, I can't really modify it for my needs.  I could download the GHUnit source and modify the implementation files, but I'd rather not do that if there's another option.

*How have others solved this problem?  IE, how can I fix my tests to support CoreData using GHUnit?*

Much thanks.

Comment: If I created an object in my main AppDelegate that encapsulated the CoreData properties/methods, would that allow me to test/mock out the necessary CoreData setup?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue before. GHUnit testing framework uses its own app delegate. So calling the delegate does not call the code you wrote within the app delegate, and its behavior can be erratic.

Generally speaking you should always handle calling your managedObjectContext(s) in a singleton that is not your app delegate. Recently I switched to GHUnit from OCunit and had to abstract all the of that functionality into a different class. It was a pain, but worth it.